# Why is the H-H Bond Dissociation Enthalpy so high?

Tags: hydrogen

"The H-H Bond Dissociation Enthalpy is the highest for a single bond between 2 atoms of any element."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bond dissociation enthalpy is the energy needed to break one mole of the bond to give separated atoms - everything being in the gas state.

For covalent bonds, bond energies and bondlengths depend on many factors:

- electron afinities,
- **sizes of atoms involved in the bond**,
- differences in their electronegativity,
- **and the overall structure of the molecule**.

There is a general trend in that the **shorter the bondlength**, the higher the **bond energy**.

Hydrogen has a relatively **small atom** and **short bondlength** hence very strong strong attractions between the atoms which will consenquently increase its bond dissociation ethalpy.

Credits

1. [Bond enthalpy (Bond energy)](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/energetics/bondenthalpies.html)
2. Inorganic chemistry bond enthalpy of Hydrogen][2](http://www.askiitians.com/forums/Inorganic-Chemistry/20/7117/hydrogen.htm)