# why bond energy of hydrogen molecule is twice the chlorine molecule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, energy

why Bond energy of Hydrogen molecule is greater than chlorine and HCl molecule?
Here's [a link](http://www.wiredchemist.com/chemistry/data/bond_energies_lengths.html)

Comment: [This could be relevant to you.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/71111/7450)

Comment: Bond energy of chlorine is less due to lone pair-lone pair repulsions.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail.?
My book claims that in the bonding molecular orbitals, there is more electron density between the two nucleus as compared to the atomic orbitals. And this more electron density acts a glue to bring two nuclues close to each other. That is why bonding molecular orbital is stronger?

Answer (score 1):

Because there are shielding electrons, meaning that the atoms can't come as close to each other. The outermost electron is the one being shared to fill a p orbital in chlorine where as it fills the s orbital in the hydrogen

Comment: Can you please explain in detail.?
My book claims that in the bonding molecular orbitals, there is more electron density between the two nucleus as compared to the atomic orbitals. And this more electron density acts a glue to bring two nuclues close to each other. That is why bonding molecular orbital is stronger.